# How to find the limit of $1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

I know that to find the overall limit of a function, I need to find the left hand side lmit (which doesn't exist) and the right hand side limit (where I am stuck).

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{+}}1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\,x\geq 1$$

The right side limit would be $-\infty$ but how do I prove that mathematically? I know that a limit doesn't exist because:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)\neq\lim_\limits{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)$$

But how do I prove that the right side limit is $-\infty$?

Comment: how can $x$ tends to Zero, when $x\geq 1$ is given?

Comment: What does $In(1/x)$ mean?

Comment: Yes I figured but then how can I find right side limit?

Comment: @kimchilover it's a function, like $logx$

Comment: @SkiMask You probably mean : $\ln(1/x)$

Comment: @Rebellos YES!! I for some reason I couldn't use it. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax is `\ln(x)` or `\ln(\frac 1x)` in the present case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first given line of the exercise is a bit weird, since finding a limit of $x\to 0^+$ when $x \geq 1$ doesn't make much sense.

The limit of $x\to 0^+$ **does** exist though, since I got a bit confused from your sayings.

Specifically :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\bigg[1+\ln\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)\bigg]= \lim_{x\to 0^+}\bigg[\ln\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)  \bigg] +1 = \infty + 1 = \infty$$

Now, the limit of $x\to 0^-$ does not have sense over $\mathbb R$, since the natural logarithmic function $\ln(Y)$, can only be defined for $Y \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1+\ln(\frac 1x)=1-\ln(x)$.

The logarithm isn't defined for $x<0$ so the left side limit (i.e. in $0^-$) makes no sense.

You can only talk about the right side limit which is in the domain of definition of $f$.

In this case $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x)=-\infty$

Adding $1$ changes nothing to the limit, but the sign is reversed since it is $1-\ln(x)$

Thus $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty$

You can also say that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 1x=+\infty$ so by composition $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\ln(\frac 1x)=\lim\limits_{u\to+\infty}\ln(u)=+\infty$